# How to update local submodules so that they match the central list of submodules?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, git-submodules

For a CI build of a project with submodules, I want to make sure that the working tree exactly matches the state that is submitted in the central repository.

After fetching and checking out the revision of the superproject, I perform the following steps to update the submodules:

```
git submodule foreach 'git reset --hard && git clean -xdf'
git submodule update --init
```

This seems to work for all cases except if a submodule is removed in the central repository. In this case, the jobs working copy still contains the removed submodule.

Also, a `git clean -xdf` on the superproject doesn't seem to touch a stale submodule.

So, is it possible to automatically detect stale local submodules and to have them removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your repo's config remains totally contaminated with the stale submodule's data. I managed to get `git clean -xdf` to work by cleaning up the repo config first.

I'm using git 1.8.1.3 from source, but the submodule removal is still a major headache. I am at a complete loss why any submodule info is stored in the repo config. We stopped using them altogether, and changed to subtree merges.

Let's say the stale submodule is in the directory `foo`.

A submodule was deleted upstream, if it's still listed in your `.git/config` file, but was deleted from `.gitmodules`. You need to do 4 things now:

- Remove submodule foo data from `.git/config`
- Remove the stale submodule's gitfile `rm foo/.git`
- Remove the stale submodule's repo `rm -rf .git/modules/foo`
- Clean now: `git clean -xdf`

Comment: But how do I detect automatically that the local submodule is stale? I'm looking for an incremental solution, i.e. which doesn't require cloning what I had cloned before. So blindly removing `.git/modules/foo` on every fetch is not an option.

Comment: To cite myself: A submodule was deleted upstream, if it's still listed in your .git/config file as a submodule, but was already deleted from .gitmodules.

Comment: Right, and I just need to `grep`/`awk`/`sed` them into two lists and compare them with `comm`. I'll accept this answer for now, but reserve the right to change the accepted answer once I (or someone else) has written the script that does all steps you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a Perl script to clean up the repo config after submodule deletion. Unfortunately, it only works if the stale submodule dir is in the root of the superproject. Because, guess what, after a submodule's git-link and .gitmodules entry was removed, git does not store where it was in the tree. Even if the repo config is totally dirty, this single info necessary for a clean removal is not available. It would be worth to write the git maintainers about this. For the moment I advise everybody to leave submodules alone.

Anyway, here's the script. After this `git clean -xdf` does work. Honest. :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                
our %mods;                                     
open MOD, ".gitmodules" or die $!;             
while (<MOD>) {                                
    if (/\[submodule "(.+)"\]/) {              
        $mods{$1} = 1;                         
     }                                          
}                                              
close MOD;                                     
rename ".git/config", ".git/config~" or die $!;
open BAK, ".git/config~";                      
unlink ".git/config~";                         
open CFG, ">.git/config";                      
our $print_on = 1;                             
while (<BAK>) {                                
    if (/\[submodule "(.+)"\]/) {              
        $print_on = $mods{$1};                 
        unlink "$1/.git" unless $print_on;     
    } elsif (/^\[/) {                          
        $print_on = 1;                         
    }                                          
    print CFG if $print_on;                    
}                                              
close BAK;                                     
close CFG;
```